# Why am I getting a Syntax Error when trying to add a placeholder to my Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to add a placeholder to my Rails 5 form field but the following code is throwing a syntax error: `<%= text_field_tag(:q), placeholder: 'Enter a city' %>`

`<%= text_field_tag(:q %>` works as expected, but adding the placeholder throws the error.

Comment: `<%= text_field_tag(:q, placeholder: 'Enter a city' )%>`

Comment: let me know if its not working

Comment: No, that doesn't work. That results in `{:placeholder=>"Enter a city"}` being pre-populated in the text field.

Comment: @Steve: because you're confusing [`text_field_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag) with `f.text_field`. They accept different parameters. Yours wants an explicit value

Comment: text_field_tag 'filename', nil, placeholder: 'your placeholder.', you need a nil as the second parameter since it is a value, text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
<%= text_field_tag :q, nil, placeholder: "Enter a city" %>
```

For more information refer [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag)